# Array of arrays (2d array) not printing in text view like I want.

Tags: java, android, textview, multidimensional-array

Sorry for the coding! I am fairly new at developing for the android and I am having trouble printing my array into the TextView the way I would like. I know some java but I am sure my coding is "newbie-ish" with a lot of bad coding. The purpose of this exercise is to help me understand Android and java better.

Here is my code. 
package com.example.taplature;

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
int counter=0;
Button prev;
Button a;
Button next;
TextView tv;
int row=6;
int col=6;

String[][] array = new String [row][col];



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        prev=((Button) findViewById(R.id.prev));
        a=((Button) findViewById(R.id.printA));
        next=((Button) findViewById(R.id.next));
        tv=((TextView) findViewById(R.id.arrayTv));

        setButtonOnClickListeners();
        setUpArray();
        printArrayToScreen();


    }

    private void printArrayToScreen() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        for(int i=0;i<row;i++)
            for(int j=0; j<col;j++)
            tv.append(array[i][j]);
    }



    private void setUpArray() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for(int i=0; i<row;i++)
            for(int j=0; j<col;j++)
            array[i][j]="-";
    }

    private void setButtonOnClickListeners() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        prev.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(counter==0)
                    counter=0;
                else
                    counter--;
            }



        });
        next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                counter++;
            }



        });
        a.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int a=1;
                array[a][counter]="12";
            }


        });


        }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

I am trying to print out a small 2d array of size 6x6 with "-" as the elements like this.

```
------
------
------
------
------
------
```

But on the android emulator it is just

```
--------------------
----------------
```

which I am assuming it just reaches the end of the screen and wraps the content?

The purpose of this app is to print out the array and the user can press next/prev to go to each column and if he presses "a" then it will put a value in the array although I have not made it far enough past printing the array on the screen properly. Also I chose a string array because I will be using numbers as well as letters.

If you guys/gals could point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`printArrayToScreen()` needs to print a newline at the end of each row:

```
private void printArrayToScreen() {
    for(int i=0;i<row;i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<col;j++)
            tv.append(array[i][j]);
        tv.append("\n"); // Append newline after every row
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess I am a little rusty with my thought processes!